# How to convert string to list of characters in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

list1=['helloworld'] convert to list2=['h' , 'e' , 'l' , 'l' , 'o', 'w', 'o',  'r', 'l', 'd']
Convert to individual item

```
list1=['helloworld']
list2=[]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    list2.append(list1[i])
print(list2)
```

Comment: First off, wouldn't you want the loop to go to `len(list1) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['helloworld']
list2=[]
for i in range(0, len(list1[0])):
   list2.append(list1[0][i])
print(list2)
```

The word is the first element of the list1 and the word has the first letter h

Comment: plz help one more time. can you reverse it?

Comment: for reason of problem solving

Comment: change the last line print(list2) --> print(list2[::-1])

Comment: this is not the answer what i ask. now i want to list2=['h' , 'e' , 'l' , 'l' , 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'] convert to list1=['helloworld']

Comment: @AshikSazal, you do this by `[''.join(list2)]`; however, this is a __different__ question from your original one and you mentioned above that @Yash Agrawal helped you with your original question; so, why not accepting? -- btw: `list(list1[0])` is an answer to your original question that does involve a loop

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis This is my second question-> now i want to list2=['h' , 'e' , 'l' , 'l' , 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'] convert to list1=['helloworld']. my first ques is solved

Comment: @AshikSazal: my comment above has the answer to your second question as well, i.e., try `list1=[''.join(list2)]`